# How can I use HighchartsReact with Ref? I want to use setChartOptions and update, but it is not possible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

How can I use HighchartsReact with Ref? I want to use setChartOptions and update, but it is not possible.

```
    const LineChart: FC<SubscriberType> = ({ client }) => {
      **const chartRef = useRef(null);**
      const initChartOptions = {
        title: {
          text: 'Loading...',
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Loading...'],
        },
        series: [{ data: [], name: 'signal' }],
      };
    
      let updateChartOptions: unknown;
    
      client.on('message', (topic: string, message: string) => {
        const signalData = JSON.parse(message);
        console.log(signalData);
        updateChartOptions = {
          title: {
            text: topic,
          },
          xAxis: {
            categories: [
              '1',
              '2',
              '3',
              '4',
              '5',
              '6',
              '7',
              '8',
              '9',
              '10',
              '11',
              '12',
              '13',
              '14',
              '15',
            ],
          },
          series: [{ data: signalData, name: 'signal' }],
        };
      });
    
      useEffect(() => {
        **chartRef.current.charts.setChartOptions(updateChartOptions);**
        **chartRef.current.charts.update(updateChartOptions);**
        console.log('LineChart');
      }, [updateChartOptions]);
    
      return (
        <div className="Main">
          <HighchartsReact
            **ref={chartRef}**
            containerProps={{ style: { width: '100%' } }}
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={initChartOptions}
            updateArgs={[true]}
            OnetoOne={this}
            allowChartUpdate
          />
        </div>
      );
    };
```

help me plz i want to live update my highcharts with Ref

I want to use ref instead of state to minimize resources

If you know how to draw high chart with minimal resources, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a chart instance by using React reference. Please check the example below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const chart = chartComponentRef.current.chart;
    chart.update(...);
  }, [...]);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-3ly4p2?file=/demo.jsx

**Docs:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official#how-to-get-a-chart-instance